# Should I call navigator.credentials.create() in my server-side code or in my client-side code?

Tags: webauthn

I was reading about WebAuthn at https://webauthn.guide/ when I came across the sentence below.

`A server would begin creating a new credential by calling navigator.credentials.create() on the client.`

Based on the statement above, should I call navigator.credentials.create() in my server-side code or in my client-side code?

Comment: Please take a look at passkeys.dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client-side code. navigator.credentials.create() is part of the WebAuthn API that's only available on the client.